# How to customize dialog icons in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, dialog, icons

I would like to make jquery dialog icons larger. Currently I use class="ui-icon ui-icon-help" icon and it looks a bit small to me (please take a look at the screenshot bellow).
[image]

I have found the information that this will change in future (more details here: https://jqueryui.pbworks.com/w/page/26308090/ThemeRoller-icon-set
)but this message is 8 years old and I do not see this updated.

I use jquery ui ver. 1.12.1.

Is there a way to make default dialog icons larger or use customized icons?

---

UPDATE 1:
A good solution has been described as Resizing Icons in jQuery-UI. I was able to change the icon and its size as on screenshot bellow:
[image]

Comment: The first solution is not a good one since icon becomes fuzzy. I check the second one, but so far I am not able to change the size... maybe I am doing something wrong... I have to work on this more...

Comment: It does not work for me so far. I am not able to change icon size (however I am able to change an icon).

Comment: OK. I have found the solution. I had to put style text in html file directly. It works now. Thank you.